# When I deploy my java artifacts to maven with source and javadocs, and then try to reference them from another project, it only downloads the main jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, jar

I am using gradle with maven-publish plugin to create my main jar, javadoc and source jar.

The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
  from sourceSets.main.allJava
  classifier "sources"
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
 classifier = 'javadoc'
 from javadoc.destinationDir
}


publishing {
    publications {
        fatJarPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourceJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
    }
}
```

It successfully creates and deploys the jar, source and javadoc. I can see all of the artifacts on my maven repo. The problem is that when I actually include this artifact in another project, it doesn't seem to find the javadoc or source jar. I am using eclipse, I have downloadsources and downloadjavadocs set to true and I can see it downloads sources and javadocs for all the 3rd party artifacts but not for my own artifact.

I was wondering if anyone might have any clue about what I could be missing that would allow me to make use the source and javadocs in other projects.

Thanks!

Comment: where do you see downloaded jars and sources, and where is yours missing, btw netbeans maven integration is much better, time to ditch eclipse

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I have had to tell it to download these explicitly I'm not sure why.

```
testCompile('junit:junit:4.8.2')
testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2', classifier: 'javadoc')
testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2', classifier: 'sources')
```

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/external-dependencies-download-including-sources-jar-and-javadoc-jar/3391

I missed the part where you said you had this set to true already.  I will leave this part in case someone stumbles here looking for them.
I use the Intellij IDE but I think I solved a similar issue by doing something similar to using this flag which is part of the eclipse plugin.

```
eclipse.classpath.downloadJavadoc = true // defaults to 'false'
```

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-get-javadocs-jar-as-part-of-dependency-download/7558/7